# Jsf How to create a Naming Container

Tags: jsf, facelets, naming-containers

I have a problem with duplicated ids in my JSF app. I've read [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428317/duplicate-id-jsf/1431295#1431295) that one of the possible solutions is to use Naming Container. Can you give me some example how to use the Naming Container to avoid duplicated ids problem? I use Facelets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what worked for me using JSF1.2 and facelets:

I discovered that neither `<ui:composition>` nor `<ui:component>` is actually a naming container, so using the same component more than once in the same form would fail with a duplicate ID exception.  This seems like a bad design, as the whole point of components is re-usability.  To get around this problem I include a `<f:subview>` within each component and set the id on it as a parameter of my component tag:

myComponent.xhtml:

```
<ui:component>      
    <f:subview id="#{id}">
        ....component code
    </f:subview>
</ui:component>
```

and the using it on other pages is simple (after setting up taglib.xml and web.xml correctly):

```
<myTagLib:myComponent id="myCompA" />
```

Comment: That solves my problem perfectly. Thanks to you Naganalf and BalusC!

Comment: sorry for down voting, but f:subview does not seem to be intended to fix the problem described in the posting OP is mentioning. This does something and something might work.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to take a step back and investigate *why* the duplicate ID problem occurs. Once you nailed the root cause down, then just fix it the "usual" way rather than creating your own `UINamingContainer` component.

There are several possible causes for duplicate ID errors which should help you further nailing it down:

- The *same* ID is used on *different* `UIComponent`s inside the *same* `UINamingContainer` component.
- *Physically different* components are bound to the *same* `UIComponent` property of the *same* bean.
- JSP only: the `f:subview` is been declared in the *parent* page instead of the *include* page.
- The *same* include page is included *multiple* times inside the *same* `UINamingContainer` component.
- A component is been dynamically built (e.g. `new UIComponent()`) *without* having an ID assigned.

Here, [`UINamingContainer`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) is under each the `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>` and `<f:subview>`.

If the above suggestions doesn't help, then update your question to include the smallest possible code snippet (thus, *without* all irrelevant code/clutter like unrelated components, libraries, HTML/CSS/JS/etc) which reproduces the exact same problem by just copy'n'paste'n'running it without any changes.

Comment: This is just like the next to the last scenario. I have a facelets custom component which I include several times inside the same page. My facelets component contains a4j:outputPanel with the problematic id. I need this id so that I can reRender the a4j:outputPanel. 

Wrapping my component contents inside h:form doesn't seem to me like a good option. I'd rather put it inside some facelets-provided UINamingContainer but I reckon there's no such thing.

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? Where are you invoking the rerender, inside or outside the custom component? What exactly do you mean with "custom component", just `ui:composition`?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue while creating my first facelets components.  I'll share what worked for me in another answer (when I get back from lunch).  You might want to update your question to be more specific.

Comment: there is a fairly easy example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428317/duplicate-id-jsf/1431295#1431295 
once you got a tag with rendered="#{baluscRox == true}" and once rendered="#{baluscRox == false}" it accesses the same object etc