# primefaces update attribute not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Whenever I run the following code on Home.xhtml page, I get the following exception. I try to call the contents of panel with `id = items` but without success. It says that compiler cannot find the component with `items` identifier.

1)part of Home.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Speak Out" action="#{statusBean.save}" ajax="true" styleClass="buttonstyle" update="items"/>                          
</h:form>


<p:panel id="items">    
    //content       
</p:panel>
```

2)Exception

```
Mar 12, 2013 1:38:04 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/Home.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "items" in view.
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findClientIds(ComponentUtils.java:249)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:222)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:81)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:53)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:300)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:181)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:125)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1643)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Mar 12, 2013 1:38:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/FreeBird_v.6] threw exception [Cannot find component with identifier "items" in view.] with root cause
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "items" in view.
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findClientIds(ComponentUtils.java:249)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:222)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:81)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:53)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:300)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:181)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:125)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1643)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: try :items, because it's outside the component tree.

Comment: @berkay you should post an answer :)

Comment: @berkay Thanks it is working, but can you explain to me why it is outside the component tree.

Comment: @AmlanKarmakar more specifically it is outside the form within which the `commandButton` is firing. You might want to wrap your panel with another form. in that case the update would be `:formId:panelId`. If you sent the `prependId` attribute to false then the `panelId` will not be preceded with `formId`.

Comment: @AmlanKarmakar see also [UIComponentBase#findComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @ Tapas Bose, thanks for explanations. @ partlov i guess i need some more reputation:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference components in JSF ajax? Cannot find component with identifier "foo" in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, shortly you should try  `:items`, because it's outside the component tree. And for more details of using ajax behavior of primefaces you can check the examples in showcase from [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprPartialTree.jsf). In addition you can use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) in this case to observe your components.
**EDIT:**
After BalusC's warning, it's correct that your problem lies on not due to the it's not inside the same component tree, because it's not in the same NamingContainer.

Standard components like `h: form` , `f: subview` and `h: dataTable` are naming containers. Most sets of components possess in some naming containers, so in your case it's outside of the  tag for that reason `:items` will be correct way to refer it.

Please refer to these posts help you understand the topic nicely:

- [Jsf How to create a Naming Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449370/jsf-how-to-create-a-naming-container)
- [Naming Container and Jsf](http://www.rponte.com.br/2008/07/01/jsf-e-naming-container/)

Comment: Uh, it's not outside the component tree. It's inside the same component tree, just not in the same `NamingContainer`. Please explain the cause properly.