# Avoiding duplicate ids when reusing facelets compositions in the same naming container

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composition

I have a `<ui:composition>` that contains a few elements with explicit ids and some ajax events which reference these ids for partial processing/updating. I encapsulated this fragment of xhtml inside the composition simply so I could use it in a few different places without having to duplicate the code. However, when I use the composition (with `<ui:include>`) more than once inside a page, I get duplicate id exceptions. It seems JSF is not wrapping each composition inside its own naming container (like `<ui:component>` does).

Is there a simple way to wrap my composition inside its own naming container?
Or do I have to use a composite component every time I want to reuse xhtml fragments inside a common naming container?

Comment: I haven't had to use it, but wrapping the composition contents in a `f:subView` seems to help, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3453154/785663).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Depending on the purpose of the `<ui:include>` template, you've several options:

1. Use `<f:subview>`. It creates another `NamingContainer` context (like as `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>`, and friends all do):

   ```
   <f:subview id="top">
       <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/some.xhtml" />
   </f:subview>
   ...
   <f:subview id="bottom">
       <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/some.xhtml" />
   </f:subview>
   ```

   The components definied in `some.xhtml` will end up getting respectively `top:` and `bottom:` prefix in their ID.

   ---
2. Turn it into a [tagfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component) which requires an `id` attribute.

   ```
   <my:some id="top" />
   ...
   <my:some id="bottom" />
   ```

   And use that ID to prefix the ID of the components in the composition.

   ```
   <ui:composition 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   >
       ...
       <h:someComponent id="#{id}_some" />
       <h:otherComponent id="#{id}_other" />
       ...
   <ui:composition>
   ```

   ---
3. Turn it into a [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info). Composite components are inherently already a `NamingContainer`, so their `id` attribute is optional. Basically, replace

   ```
   <ui:composition 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   >
       ...
   <ui:composition>
   ```

   by

   ```
   <ui:component 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
       xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
   >
       <cc:interface>
           <!-- This is optional. -->
       </cc:interface>
       <cc:implementation>
           ...
           <h:someComponent id="some" />
           <h:otherComponent id="other" />
           ...
       </cc:implementation>
   <ui:component>
   ```

   This way you can use it as follows:

   ```
   <my:some id="top" />
   ...
   <my:some id="bottom" />
   ```

   The components definied in `<cc:implementation>` will end up getting respectively `top:` and `bottom:` prefix in their ID  (note again, the composite component's `id` attribute is optional, JSF will otherwise autogenerate one).

   ---

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: Thanks once again @BalusC. I thought you must be able to do something like the <f:subview> option - good to know.

Comment: @BalusC , if I use this f:subview , can I continue using the java scripts in the same manner ? or javascripts (which using ids of the page) need to change accordingly?

Answer (score 8):

When you include more than once the same `ui:composition` the id are duplicated. The solution is to specifiy a particular `ui:param` within the `ui:include`.

Assuming you're including mycomposition.xhtml you can do something similar:

```
<ui:include src="mycomposition.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="idPrefix" value="first"/>
</ui:include>

...

<ui:include src="mycomposition.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="idPrefix" value="second"/>
</ui:include>
```

Then in the mycomposition.xhtml you should declare the ids as follows (for instance a h:outputText):

```
<h:outputText id="#{idPrefix}_text" value="My Awesome Text here"/>
```

Now you can reference the id in the rest of yout page as `#{idPrefix}_text`.