# JSF includes and duplicate HTML IDs

Tags: jsf, include, facelets

I have a main HTML page which includes *detail.xhtml* and *duo.xhtml*.

Now *duo.xhtml* also includes *detail.xhtml*, which results in duplicate IDs which of course it not working. What can I do to solve this problem? I don't want to manage redundant code.

Main:

```
<ui:composition ...>
  <ui:define name="center">
    <ui:insert name="insertDuo">
      <ui:include src="/includes/duo.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
...
<p:dialog header="x" widgetVar="detDialog" id="dlg" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">
  <ui:insert name="insertDetail">
    <ui:include src="/includes/detail.xhtml" />
  </ui:insert>
```

Duo:

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:dialog header="y" widgetVar="newDuoDialog" id="newDuoDlg" modal="true" >
        <p:layout id="layout">

            <p:layoutUnit position="west">
                <ui:insert name="insertDetailStmt">
                    <h:form id="stmtDetailForm">
                        <ui:include src="/includes/detail.xhtml" />
                    </h:form>
                </ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>
```

Detail:

```
<p:accordionPanel id="accordion">
```

Reference to components:

```
<p:commandButton value="z" update=":accordion:duoDlgForm2:pickList"/>
```

Comment: and how would my `<h:outputLabel>`s for example refer to the `<h:inputText>` ? I think your second sentences lacks detail. I can't understand what you advise me to do exactly

Comment: I heavily disagree with @DarkFalcon since looks he has not worked with JSF before. Anyway, seems like you're not prepending the ID from the container e.g. `<h:form>`, `<h:datatable>`; or you're effectively using duplicate IDs in both pages, so just change them. It would be better if you provide a code sample.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Correct, in fact, I didn't see the tag. I saw xhtml and assumed HTML IDs. My apologies.

Comment: @DarkFalcon in the end, JSF will generate plain HTML. The problem is how you define the HTML generation, and nobody can save you from telling your code to generate a `<form>` inside another `<form>` and making your page never firing a request :) (but that's outside the scope of this question).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, I am using duplicate IDs because it refers to the same page. I cannot simply change them, the effect was still the same

Comment: Duplicate of [Avoiding duplicate ids when reusing facelets compositions in the same naming container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552654/avoiding-duplicate-ids-when-reusing-facelets-compositions-in-the-same-naming-con)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to BalusC, I was able to solve the problem. Just use

```
<f:subview id="fromMain">
    <ui:include src="/includes/regelDetail.xhtml" />
</f:subview>
```

and when referred from main, the element's name is *fromMain:accordion*