# How to call the same method after every include of a .xhtml page in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, onload, uiinclude

I have the following part of a .xhtml page:

```
<ui:composition template="./templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="mainContent">

    <ui:include src="include/includeAbleEditor.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="includeParam" value="MyClass" />

    </ui:include>



    <ui:include src="include/includeAbleEditor.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="includeParam" value="YourClass" />
    </ui:include>

</ui:define>
```

In the "includeAbleEditor.xhtml" I want to call a method after it was included (In this case this should happend two times).

Now I tried to solve it like this: (metadata tag is part of the includeAbleEditor.xhtml)

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{editor.onload}" />
    <f:attribute name="textFieldId" value="#{includeParam}" />
</f:metadata>
```

The Problem:

The method is being called only once. But it should be called two times. Once with the parameter "MyClass" and once with "YourClass".

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There can be only one `<f:metadata>` in the entire view and it must be in the top level view. Unlike e.g. `<f:view>`, they don't "extend" each other and all others will be ignored.

You actually don't need it here. It's only necessary whenever you need to attach `<f:viewParam>` and/or `<f:viewAction>` to the specific view. The `<f:event>` doesn't require a `<f:metadata>`. It will just be hooked to the parent `UIComponent`. It was during JSF 2.0/2.1 ages (when `<f:viewAction>` didn't exist) being abused to have a hook to invoke a listener after `<f:viewParam>` values are being set. It's just for self-documentary purposes being placed in the same `<f:metadata>` as where all `<f:viewParam>`s are.

So, just get rid of it.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{editor.onload(includeParam)}" />
```

That said, `postAddToView` is likely a better event to hook this all on. And to avoid "Duplicate component ID" errors over all place later on, consider wrapping it in `<f:subview>` or making it a composite.

#### See also:

- [When using <ui:composition> templating, where should I declare the <f:metadata>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856847/when-using-uicomposition-templating-where-should-i-declare-the-fmetadata/)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)
- [Avoiding duplicate ids when reusing facelets compositions in the same naming container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552654/avoiding-duplicate-ids-when-reusing-facelets-compositions-in-the-same-naming-con/)

Comment: there is an error....
Caused by: javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /include/includeAbleEditor.xhtml 58,76 listener="#{editor.onload(includeParam)}" Error Parsing: #{editor.onload(includeParam)}

Comment: So, you're still on legacy Servlet 2.5 or so? Didn't expect that these days. Well, if you can't upgrade to Servlet 3.0+ (released more than 5 years ago already), stick to `f:attribute` workaround then. This "error" is not further related to the concrete problem.

Comment: Now I have do it like this: 

 <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{editor.onload}">
  <f:attribute name="textFieldId" value="#{includeParam}" />
 </f:event>

here's a snip of the method "onload" :

String id = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("textFieldId");

But the id is null. The event object isn't null! weird