# Reuse some .xhtml pages on a JSF primefaces application

Tags: jsf, facelets

I developing a simple application using JSF and PrimeFaces and here's a problem that I'm facing:

These are managed beans that have a `Person` property:

- `ClientBean`
- `EmployeeBean`

I have the `person.xhtml` that shows the data from a person. I include the `person.xhtml` on a `client.xhtml` and `employee.xhtml`. I need to create two `person.xhtml` because I'm using different beans. What I want to do is something like that:

```
<c:set var="person" value="clientBean.person" /> 
<ui:include src="person.xhtml"/>

<c:set var="person" value="employeeBean.person" /> 
<ui:include src="person.xhtml"/>
```

And in my `person.xhtml` I can use `#{person.name}` , `#{person.dateOfBirth}`.
I searched and use `<c:set/>` in JSF is wrong.

Anyone can help?

Comment: @Nambari yes. I use templates to construct the pages. What I need is how to get data from different beans and use in the same .xhtml page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass it as `<ui:param>`.

```
<ui:include src="person.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="person" value="#{clientBean.person}" /> 
</ui:include>
<ui:include src="person.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="person" value="#{employeeBean.person}" /> 
</ui:include>
```

Register `person.xhtml` if necessary as a tag file to make it look better, see also [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

```
<my:personForm value="#{clientBean.person}" /> 
<my:personForm value="#{employeeBean.person}" />
```

Beware of duplicate component ID errors. See also [Avoiding duplicate ids when reusing facelets compositions in the same naming container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552654/avoiding-duplicate-ids-when-reusing-facelets-compositions-in-the-same-naming-con/).