# Parameter always null on ui:composite xhtml page

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm passing a parameter to a `<ui:composite>` page as a solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275769/reuse-some-xhtml-pages-on-a-jsf-primefaces-application/31275923?noredirect=1#comment50546096_31275923). It works perfectly in other cases, but in this one, the parameter passed is always `null`. Here's the code:

dados.xhtml -> it's placed at resources/protocolo/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="protocolo" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:panel header="Protocolo #{protocolo.id}   |     #{protocolo.situacao.descricao}">
        <p:panelGrid style="text-align: center; width: 100%;" >
            <p:row>
                <p:column> Operação </p:column>
                <p:column> #{protocolo.operacao.descricao} </p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row>
                <p:column> Data entrada </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{protocolo.dataEntrada}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                    </h:outputText> 
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <br/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</composite:implementation>


</html>
```

Here's where i call this composite page:

```
#{protocolo.id}
<protocolo:dados protocolo="#{protocolo}"/>
```

Calling `protocolo.id` returns the correct id for the entity, but inside the composite, it returns `null`. I'm using other composite pages inside this xhtml and it's working perfectly.

Anyone can help?

Comment: But I'm using other composite pages without `cc.attrs` and they are working. Do you know why?

Comment: Then those were not composite components, but tagfiles or includes. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen to learn the difference.