# Setting Bean from pure HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

Due to accessibility of the dynamic ID I cannot use JSF `<h:inputHidden/>` and instead must use HTML:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="sound_#{recordingTag}" value="#{wavRecorded}"/>
```

When I use JSF, the value gets updated back to the backing bean, however the ID is incomplete/incorrect because of a variable in `#{recordingTag}`. When I use HTML only, ID works fine and I can access the element in JS, but the value doesn't go back into my bean.

Essentially I need this element to act just Like `<h:inputHidden/>`, however the ID attribute needs to behave like `<input/>`.

This is all being done in a `UI:include` source page. `wavRecorded` and `recordingTag` are `UI:param` elements.

Comment: I'd take a step back and fix the template/include/tag as such that you can simply use `id="sound"`.

Comment: Issue is there are multiple Includes of this page on some pages

Comment: For exactly this reason JSF has `<f:subview>` and `<cc:implementation>`.

Comment: I'll look into that. thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this answers the X of your XY-problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21552654

Comment: I need to make subviews (with different IDs) in a datatable. based on a property in the var. is this doable?

Comment: Yes. Namely, ID doesn't need to be dynamic at all.