# JSF: duplicate component id exception when including the same facelets tag twice

Tags: jsf

I have a facelets tag like this:

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:outputText value="#{label}"/>
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{value}"/>
    <h:message for="input"/>
</ui:composition>
```

Now if I inlcude this facelets tag twice on the same page, I get an exception complaining about duplicate compoment ids. One solution proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572756/1785730 was to supply a prefix for the id. However, I find it cumbersome having to come up with an id prefix every time I use this facelets tag. By the way, I don't need the id of the h:inputText outside of the tag.

So I'm thinking of two ways how I can fix this:

1. Is there a way to link the h:message to the h:inputText without having to specify ids?
2. If not, I could wrap the tag with a NamingContainer. Which element would be appropriate for that? I can't use h:form here, because that tag already goes into a form.

Comment: Why not do '3' from the link you refer to?

Comment: I was looking for a more lightweight solution. I'd prefer to stay with facelets.

Comment: Besides, composite components are *one* component in the end. My tag fits right into a three column h:panelGrid.

Comment: 1) would otherwise already be covered by the answer you found. 2) is already covered by the answer you found. So I'm not really understanding why you're asking this duplicate question.

Comment: In case you're refering to f:subview: that has a required id parameter, which doesn't get me any further. If I just can't do it the way I want and my best bet is to have an id parameter for my tag, that would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score -2):

Your page should be like this

```
<f:view contracts="default" transient="false">
    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                inputs
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</f:view>
```

inside ui composition you should have ui define and in it form and inputs.

Comment: How would that solve the duplicate id exception when including my tag twice?

Comment: In every form every tags must have unique id. the first improve your page, you are using facelets composition without main template, second be sure what in every h:form components have unique id.